# Updating a field in a class from another class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I am having some trouble trying to re-update a textview in another activity. I am making a calorie calculator app. I have a textview to display the total calories. it is setText using a for loop in the main :

```
for(int i = 0; i < backCal.size(); i++){
    sum += backCal.get(i);
}
totalcalories.setText(""+sum);
```

And every time the user alternate a different ingredient, I want this sum to re calculate the given calories of the replacement ingredient auto.

Without user clicking the button.
code for the alternate ingredient is in the **custom listview class**:

```
alternate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick (View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //
        if (x == 1) {

            alternate.setText("Bck");

            String a = AltIngredients.get(position);
            String b = "" + calA.get(position);
            ingredients1.setText("" + a);
            cal1.setText("" + b);

            x--;

        } else {

            alternate.setText("Alt");

            String a = ingredients.get(position);
            String b = "" + cal.get(position);
            ingredients1.setText("" + a);
            cal1.setText("" + b);
            x++;
        }
    }
});

} else {
    alternate.setEnabled(false);
}

return rowView1;
```

and every time user alternate back to previous ingredient, the total calories should update.

so initially if it was chicken at 200 calories,eggs 50cal, total cal should be 250 and if altered to vege which is 100cal it would change to 150cal. just an example. do advice me futher.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear about the issue,Any way i will try to solve it out.
You need to display total calories as per the ingredients selection by user right?
User is able to select Ingredients from a list view then we have to recalculate the value..

In simple steps

- You need to store selected ingredients in a list
- Write a method to calculate and display the total calorie from the selected
  ingredients.
- Whenever user select  or deselect any ingredient update
  the list and call the method to calculate and display.

In case of multiple activities use shared preference or intent extra to pass list of ingredients and call the method to calculate the calories in onresume method of activity so that its get updated every time when calorie display activity shown

Hopes it gives you some Idea ...

Comment: yes thanks for the suggestion man. i  got it pretty much. i arent very good at android so couldnt explain it in a better way.

Comment: @user3884188 dont take it -ve votes seriously, it always happens, It  will become better after  posting one or two questions.. cheers  happy development :)